# Packages are not getting restored

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to build a project from downloaded source code using VS2017 community edition. Got following error

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.2.0.637442-pre1\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.props.
```

not sure whats the issue. I tried

1. Delete packages folder and restore packages.
2. Delete obj and bin folder. Tried to clean rebuild.

Comment: Try to clean the project from visual studio and then rebuild it.

Comment: It seems you have not rightly installed some plugin which used by that downloaded object. Would you post the full project? so that I can test it for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, restart Visual Studio, cleaning and building the solution most times is not enough.

Try unloading the project in Visual Studio and edit the csproj file.
 Search for that props file reference in the file. Sometimes it gets duplicatedthe current version and one outdated version as well. Remove the old one and reload the project.

Check in your Forms, Android/iOS if the `csproj` is referencing the same Xamarin.Forms version,and are no strange lines/characters.

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="x.x.x.xxxxx" />
```

In the last resort, try to downgrade the XamarinForms version and check if it helps.